# Loading a level in unity 5.5.0f3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 5.5.03f and I want to reload a screen once the character hits an obstacle, I do have the box colliders attached to both. But the code that I have is not working.

This is the code that I have for restarting the screen:

```
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
     .
     .
     .
    void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){

    // get the current scene name 
    string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;

    // load the same scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);

}
```

I am using C# as my programming language for unity.
Any help and advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine.
But the function name would be **OnCollisionEnter2D**, not **onCollisionEnter2D**

Comment: Oh I see that now, thank you so much, I really appreciate it